# Limit with cube root conjugate

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-limit-theorems

Calculate the limit as $n -> \infty$ of $$n(\sqrt[3]{(1+1/n)} -1)$$

Summary of my work:

1. Put n into the denominator in the form of $1/n$
2. Multiplied by $n/n$
3. Multiplied by conjugate of numerator: $[\sqrt[3]{(n^3 + n^2)^2} + 2\sqrt[3]{n^3 +n^2} + n^2]/[\sqrt[3]{(n^3 + n^2)^2} + 2\sqrt[3]{n^3 +n^2} + n^2]$
4. Multiplied by $((1/n^2)/(1/n^2))$

Ended up with a final answer of 1/2

Comment: Actually, the limit is equal to $1/3$.

Comment: If you write it as $\root 3\of{1+1/n}-1\over 1/n$, can you regognize the limit as the derivative of some function evaluated at $0$?

Comment: I don't think there should be a $2$ in your "conjugate".

Answer (score 2):

$$n\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=n\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt[3]{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1}\right)$$

which tends to $\frac{1}{3}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Could u please state you conjugate?
Maybe that's my source of error?

Comment: My "conjugate" was $\sqrt[3]{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1$. To see where this comes from recall that:
$x^{3}-y^{3}=(x-y)(x^{2}+xy+y^{2})$. Take $x=a^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $y=b^{\frac{1}{3}}$.